# Get text from span using cheerio and node.js

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Hi I'm trying to the text inside the span, the one with "Text to get"

I'm getting the div with class="membership-limit-section capture-area" using cheerio and node.js, but I can't get the text from the span.

I have this function to get the div and I can see that it does have more elements inside, but I can«t get the text

```
 url = "URLdata";
      rp(url)
        .then(function (html) {
          var getHtml = $("div[class='membership-limit-section capture-area']", html);
          console.log(getHtml);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

```
<body data-n-head>
  <div id="_nuxt">
    <div id="__layout">
      <div class="app-wrapper purge-css-ignore">
        <div class="main-container">
          <section class="el-container">
            <main
              class="el-main auto-height-on-print capture-area"
              id="components-root"
            >
              <div data-v-5cc60f9e>
                <div data-v-5cc60f9e class="responsive-section">
                  <div
                    data-v-7ce2662e
                    data-v-5cc60f9e
                    class="membership-limit-section capture-area"
                  >
                    <div data-v-5cc60f9e class="dividends">
                      <div>
                        <div
                          data-v-593f497d
                          class="el-card capture-area is-always-shadow"
                        >
                          <h1 data-v-593f497d>Test</h1>
                          <div
                            role="alert"
                            class="el-alert el-alert--warning is-light"
                            data-v-593f497d
                          >
                            <div class="el-alert__content">
                              <span class="el-alert__title">Text to get</span>
                              <i
                                class="el-alert__closebtn el-icon-close"
                                style="display: none;"
                              ></i>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </main>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can someone help on how to get the text from the span?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The following selector will do for that specific response: `.membership-limit-section.capture-area .el-alert__title`

Then you can use `.text()` to obtain the text of the `span`.

```
var getHtml = $(
  ".membership-limit-section.capture-area .el-alert__title",
  html
);

console.log(getHtml.text())
```

**Update:**

> gurufocus.com/stock/KO/dividend I want the "Continuous dividend
>   increase since 1963" but I cannot get it. I'm able to parse info from
>   yahoo using cheerio, but not from this website

The content you want to scrape, is loaded on the client side using XHR. So you won't be able to parse it directly using `request` & `cheerio` since that part is not being returned, either you hit the endpoint returning that data directly, or you use `puppeteer` on the main site.

When scraping with requests and cheerio, always log the content and see if what you want to parse is present.

Comment: The console.log returns notting :( so it's not getting the content

Comment: Sorry, check updated answer, there was a space, it should be: `.membership-limit-section.capture-area .el-alert__title` instead of `.membership-limit-section capture-area .el-alert__title`

Comment: Still nothing... I can't understand why I can't get the value. I have other things working with cheerio but I can't put this one to get the text.

Comment: I'm testing that code with that body and it works perfectly fine. So either that's not the response body or you're doing something else.

Comment: If I load the html using cheerio I can get the text, but when reading the HTML from the rp, I can't get the text. I updated the post to the full body of the request. 
Thanks a lot for the answers :)

Comment: then the response is not returning that. Share the URL and I'll be able to help you, otherwise I don't have enought information

Comment: https://www.gurufocus.com/stock/KO/dividend
I want the "Continuous dividend increase since 1963" but I cannot get it. I'm able to parse info from yahoo using cheerio, but not from this website.
Thansk

Comment: Check updated answer, that's being loaded using Javascript, you need to use `puppeteer`

Answer (score 0):

The following selector will do for that specific response: `const a=$('div.membership-limit-section capture-area').innerText` Then just use `a` variable it has text of span tag.